# How to perform logical tests on time values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an excel sheet where one column contains a time field, where the values are the time of day entered as four digits:  i.e. 0845, 1630, 1000.

I've read this into a pandas dataframe for analysis, one piece of which is labeling each time as day or evening.  To do this, I first changed the datatype and format:

```
# Get start time as time

df['START_TIME'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['START_TIME'],format='%H%M').dt.time
```

Which gets the values looking like:

```
08:45:00
16:30:00
10:00:00
```

The new dtype is object.

When I try to perform a logical test on that field, i.e.

```
# Create indicator of whether course begins before or after 4:00 PM

df['DAY COURSE INDICATOR'] = df['START_TIME'] < '16:00:00'
```

I get a Type Error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of >'datetime.time' and 'str'

or syntax error if I remove the quotes.

What is the best way to create that indicator; how do I work with stand-alone time values?  Or am I better off just leaving them as integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare a datetime.time and a str but you certainly can compare a datetime.time and a datetime.time:

```
import datetime
df['DAY COURSE INDICATOR'] = df['START_TIME'] < datetime.time(16, 0)
```

Comment: I tried this, but now get a different type error:  descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'.

Comment: @GaryM you need to use the standard [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module as I have in my snippet, not the `pandas.datetime` class.

Comment: it seems like you're confused (understandably) about the different time representations here. when you call `pd.to_datetime()` on your Series of strings, pandas converts these strings to the numpy `datetime64` type. `dt` is a handy Series accessor that, when you do `dt.time`, will convert these `datetime64`s into `datetime.time`, which is a type of object from the `datetime` module in the standard library. `pandas.datetime` is just `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you did in the first place:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['START_TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S') < pd.to_datetime('16:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S')
```

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'START_TIME': ['08:45']})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['START_TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S') < pd.to_datetime('16:00:00', format='%H:%M:%S')
0    True
Name: START_TIME, dtype: bool
```